# How can i create loop to in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried this :

```
Select  
    Year,
    NewProjects,
    CompletedProject,
    InactiveCancelled,
    (case when year(ReceptionDate) = '2013' then (14 + count(*)/*NEwProject*/) end) as ActiveProjects,
    (case  When (Year = 2013) then (ActiveProjects - CompletedProject - InactiveCancelled) end as CarriedForward,
    /* User gave me carried forward project for 2012 which is = 14 so i have to continue loop from that*/
from 
    Table1
```

- Active project = CarriedForward project from previous year + NEw Project
- Carriedforward project =  active project from that year - completed project from same year - cancelled and inactive project

This will return the carried forward for next year

When I add value in Case and get value for carried forward projects for the next year. Question is how can i use that value and add again in new project for next year within same SQL query

Carriedforward for 2012 = 14 this value is constant I have to create a loop to count the rest of the active and carried forward project.

I added 14 in Newprojct and got active project for 2013

Then from that I subtract value for completed project and inactive project and got carried forward for 2014 = 29

Now I want to add that 29 in new project with in same sql query.

```
Year    NewProjects ActiveProjects  CompletedProject    InactiveCancelled   CarriedForward
2012        11           NULL              1                    1                NULL
2013        31            45               5                    11                29
2014        44           NULL              16                   14               NULL
2015        45           NULL              24                   20               NULL
2016        30           NULL              24                   10               NULL
```

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's **carried forward** - not "forword" ....

Comment: The sample data that you provided is a desired outcome or sample data in the table?

Comment: Why would you want to loop???  SQL is a set-based language.

Comment: Desired outcome. I am facing issues getting an active project and carried forward and they both are dependent on each other

Comment: Can you please provide the sample data from the table? Helps visualizing

Comment: I agree with @Eric , you might end up using something else instead of loop

Comment: ID RequestName Status ReceptionDate CancelledInactive CompletedProject
1301 Project1  Completed 8/15/2017 NULL 11/19/2018
1302 Project2 Inactive 1/1/2013 Cancelled 7/1/2014
1303 Project3 Completed 6/28/2017 NULL 9/6/2018
1304 Project4 Completed 3/31/2017 NULL 1/17/2019
1305 Project5 Inactive 1/1/2013 Cancelled 7/1/2014

Comment: yes, but what should i use. the carryforward value I get I wanted to use that and add in next year new project and then from that value I need to subtract completed and canceled project to get carry forward for next year

Comment: Here's a guide how to ask proper question.  Without knowing how your data looks like, there's no way anybody can help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The results of the query you have tried contains an equation involving ActiveProjects and InactiveCancelled which I assume are counts. However, the unformatted sample data you provided above does not contain columns for ActiveProjects or InactiveCancelled. If you hope to get answer it would be helpful to provide a complete set of sample data that we can run and test out our potential solutions. I know this not correct, but something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=25b68f64f21c30db6e7a931d9a7f4cb4) is what I am talking about.

Comment: Thank you very much  Isaac. Yes, what you have mentioned is right.                                   2012 Carryforwards = 14 (Which is constant)
                + 2013 new project (Count (*)) = Active projects for 2013 - Inactive and Completed project (2013)= Carry forward for 2014
          +
             2014(New Projects) = Active projects for 2014
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4460c991b48c528fe75d0225d4393173